# objective C process other events within while loop

Tags: objective-c, json, multithreading, events

Is there a way to force your application to process other events? I have a loop that is supposed to wait 10 seconds for a json response. The problem seems to be that the loop processes before the didReceiveData event can run.

JsonArray is an NSArray property.

Here is my code in Session.m:

```
-(BOOL)logIn
{
    JsonArray = nil;
    if (([Password class] == [NSNull class]) || ([Password length] == 0))
        return NO;

    if (([Username class] == [NSNull class]) || ([Username length] == 0))
        return NO;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_ALL_PROPERTIES]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:10.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    if (!connection)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    int time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

    while (!JsonArray)
    {
        if (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - time == 10)
        {
            NSLog(@"breaking loop");
            break;
        }
        // process events here
    }

    if (!JsonArray) return NO;

    NSLog(@"JsonArray not nil");
    return YES;
}
```

didReceiveData handler:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Data received");
    NSError *e = nil;
    JsonArray = nil;

    JsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
    if (!JsonArray)
    {
        JsonArray = nil;
        Connected = NO;
        return;
    }
    Connected = YES;
}
```

Comment: Don't wait in a hard loop. Why do you want to?

Comment: Your delegate method isn't going to be called until `logIn` finishes.

Comment: I would like to be able to use a method that returns a boolean based on whether or not data was received.

Comment: That's not how it works with NSURLConnection. You would have to use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embrace the asynchronous nature of what you're trying to do. Remove the return from the `login` method and add a completion block instead. Store the completion block in a property (copy) and call it from `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

```
typedef void (^MYCompletionHandler)(BOOL success);

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^MYCompletionHandler)(bool *) completion;

- (void)loginUserWithCompletion:(MYCompletionHandler)completion {

    self.completion = completion;

    // start your login processing here
}

// when the login response is received
self. completion(##DID_IT_WORK##);
```

Your current code doesn't work because the main runloop isn't running while your hard loop is running, so the delegate methods are queued waiting to be processed. Don't try to work around it with the run loop, deal with the asynchronous nature properly.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused on how to add a completion block to my logIn method.

Comment: As in, when you call the login method? Made a quick edit. Is it just that the Xcode auto-complete didn't add a parameter name?

Comment: As in what do I need to add to my logIn method? I'm new to objective C so I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: More code added. Basically, the code defines a block type, a property to store a block in and a block on the login method. In login method, save the block and start the connection. In the connection callback, call the completion block with status.

Answer (score 1):

The `didReceiveData` method will be called when the data has been received. If you need to process the data returned, do it in the delegate method.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // process your data in here     
}
```

The `logIn` function has to finish before `didReceiveData` will be called. You cannot block for a response. That's the nature of NSURLConnection.

Comment: I understand that. Perhaps I should edit my question to make it more clear.